# Why /MD option alwasys transformed to /MDd in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I'm trying to compile the sigc++ library on windows. I set up the project setting -> C/C++ Code generation -> Runtime library = Multi Threaded DLL (/MD) in Debug mode.

I can check the C/C++ -> Command Line All Options window that /MD is set.

When I compile this project the /MD switch is transformed to /MDd and my application crash.

I downloaded the project from here:
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libsigc++/2.2/libsigc++-2.2.10.tar.bz2

There is a VS2010 solution there. I want to compile this project in Debug mode, but with /MD switch.

Comment: What is the setting you selected for the project that *links* the library?

Comment: What settings do you think? Here is my all settings for link:/OUT:"Win32\Debug\sigc-vc100-d-2_0.dll" /NOLOGO /DLL "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Win32\Debug\sigc-vc100-d-2_0.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PGD:"Z:\vs-port\libsigc++-2.2.10\MSVC_Net2010\Win32\Debug\sigc-vc100-d-2_0.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE:NO /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE

Comment: Not what I asked, but we can now see that you are building a DLL instead of a static library.  That's pretty unusual for open source projects.  It is *really* important that any other project that uses that DLL is built with the same /MD setting.  The debug and release versions of the CRT do not mix well, a crash is the common outcome.

Comment: Yes, I want to build DLLs.. And I use always the same CRT, and the same /MD settings, and everything is working except sigc++. I don't understandstand whats happening. Other libraries has not got this issue.